# Javascript: how to delay the content function

Tags: javascript, function, listener, delay, delayed-execution

I have

```
Myitem1.MyFunc();
Myitem2.MyFunc();

function MyFunc(){
  if (okToUpdate){
    //we weren't here from anywhere within the last 100 milliseconds
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, `okToUpdate` variable is updated not immediately, so it needs at least 100 milliseconds from the previous call of the function to have the correct value.
How to make MyFunc be executed with the delay?

Comment: use settimeout() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
       Myitem1.MyFunc();
},100)
```

will do the trick. If you explain what you want exactly I can give you exact timing code.

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you

```
var clrTime=null;

MyFunc(){
    clrTime=setTimeout(function(){
        if (okToUpdate){
            // your code to do 
        }
    },100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using callbacks or promises would be the clean solution. Not some kind of busy waiting implemented with timeouts.

Have a look into [publish/subscribe pattern.](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `setTimeout()` function. Something like this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){MyFunc()},100);
}
</script>

<body onload="myFunction()">
</body>
```

[setTimeout() method](http://www.whiterootmedia.com/database/dusty_arlia/settimeout_method.html)